# Local properties of Baire 1 functions

Tags: real-analysis

A Baire 1 function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ need not be bounded.  However, [thanks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550975/baire-one-function-with-a-finite-supremum-on-closed-interval) to the Baire category theorem, we know there is $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and a sub-interval $(c, d) \subset [0,1]$ such that $(\forall x\in (c, d))( |f(x)|\leq N)$.  In other words, a Baire 1 function may not be bounded on the unit interval, we know it is bounded on some **sub-interval**.

Similarly, a Baire 1 function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ may have infimum equal to $0$, but there is always some sub-interval $(c, d)\subset [0,1]$ where $f$ has non-zero infimum.

I am curious what other nice properties Baire 1 functions can have that fail on the unit interval, but do hold on some sub-interval.  I would also be happy with examples for e.g. upper semi-continuous functions.

Comment: Probably not relevant towards an answer, but a possibly interesting parallel: **(1)** If $f$ is Baire $1,$ then $f$ is bounded on some subset that is an interval with positive length. **(2)** If $f$ is Lebesgue measurable, then $f$ is bounded on some subset that is closed with positive Lebesgue measure (by Luzin's theorem). As an after-thought, in (2) "positive Lebesgue measure" can be improved to "positive Borel measure", and even to "positive Jordan content", although this doesn't mathematically strengthen the result. Also, "closed set" can be improved to "nowhere dense perfect set" . . .

Answer (score 5):

Let $ s:[0;1]\to[0;1]$ be the average binary digit **partial** function defined as follows:

$$ s(x)\ :=\ \lim_{n=\infty}\quad s_n(x) $$

where
$$ s_n(x)\, :=\,\ \frac
      1n\cdot \sum_{k=1}^n b_{-k}(x) $$
and $\ b_k(x)\ $ are the binary digits of $\ x.$

Borel's theorem tells us that $\ s(x)=\frac12\ $ for all
$\ x\in[0;1]\ $ except for Lebesgue measure $\ 0.$
Nevertheless, the following popular question was open for a rather long time:

$\qquad$ does there exist $\ x\in(0;1)\ $ (an open interval)

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$ such that $\ s(x)=x\,?$

I answered this question and more in the year 1959;
in particular, I replaced function $\ f(x):=x\ $ by
any function from a larger set of functions:

**Theorem**   Let $\ f:[0;1]\to[0;1]\ $ be an
arbitrary Baire 1 function. Then for arbitrary
$ \emptyset \ne [a;b]\subseteq [0;1] $ there exist continuum many $\ x\in[a;b]\ $ such that
$$ s(x)\ =\ f(x). $$